# JVM Crash Due to Thread ConcurrentGCThread due to EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java, crash, jvm

I have a Java server which is running on Tomcat 8 with Java 8 minor version 192, I am trying to generate 300 large reports (maximum of 5 in parallel) - at some point the Java virtual machine is crashing with an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. I thought it was a memory issue, but when I looked at the heap during GC events and the free memory of the OS, it appears that it's probably not the issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with HotSpot Java 8 version 192?

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000063f80ad0, pid=10364, tid=0x0000000000001dc4
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_192-b12) (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.192-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xb0ad0]
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001bac0800):  ConcurrentGCThread [stack: 0x000000001bd00000,0x000000001be00000] [id=7620]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000008

Stack: [0x000000001bd00000,0x000000001be00000],  sp=0x000000001bdff778,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xb0ad0]

=>0x000000001bac0800 (exited) ConcurrentGCThread [stack: 0x000000001bd00000,0x000000001be00000] [id=7620]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

heap address: 0x0000000700000000, size: 3072 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x00000007c0000000

Heap:
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 2685424K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 1255 young (1285120K), 86 survivors (88064K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000014e00000,0x0000000015400000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011600000

Marking Bits (Prev, Next): (CMBitMap*) 0x000000000252c018, (CMBitMap*) 0x000000000252c070
 Prev Bits: [0x0000000015a00000, 0x0000000018a00000)
 Next Bits: [0x0000000018a00000, 0x000000001ba00000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000e90000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=156616Kb max_used=156635Kb free=89143Kb
 bounds [0x00000000034c0000, 0x000000000cf20000, 0x00000000124c0000]
 total_blobs=38569 nmethods=37706 adapters=772
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 111205.798 Thread 0x000000001f9f7800 nmethod 56988 0x000000000ad0f5d0 code [0x000000000ad0f720, 0x000000000ad0f850]
Event: 111205.804 Thread 0x000000001f9f5000 nmethod 56989 0x0000000008e6b410 code [0x0000000008e6b580, 0x0000000008e6b9a8]
Event: 111205.804 Thread 0x000000001f9f7800 56987       3       java.util.Random::nextBytes (56 bytes)
Event: 111205.805 Thread 0x000000001f9f7800 nmethod 56987 0x0000000008bb5b90 code [0x0000000008bb5d20, 0x0000000008bb6188]
Event: 111240.018 Thread 0x000000001f9f4000 56990       4       com.compuware.apm.agent.introspection.servlet.impl.JavaxHttpServletRequestWrapper::<init> (22 bytes)
Event: 111240.022 Thread 0x000000001f9f4000 nmethod 56990 0x000000000399d290 code [0x000000000399d3c0, 0x000000000399d518]
Event: 111269.830 Thread 0x000000001f9f6800 56991       4       java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::sumCount (48 bytes)
Event: 111269.837 Thread 0x000000001f9f6800 nmethod 56991 0x000000000ac8a390 code [0x000000000ac8a4c0, 0x000000000ac8a618]
Event: 111336.508 Thread 0x000000001f9f7800 56992   !   3       sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor353::newInstance (49 bytes)
Event: 111336.510 Thread 0x000000001f9f7800 nmethod 56992 0x000000000b78ea90 code [0x000000000b78ec60, 0x000000000b78f238]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 111341.340 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=50780 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 2719920K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 1352 young (1384448K), 74 survivors (75776K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 111341.482 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=50781 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 1417712K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 81 young (82944K), 81 survivors (82944K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 111343.633 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=50781 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 2711920K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 1342 young (1374208K), 81 survivors (82944K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 111343.803 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=50782 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 1437872K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 98 young (100352K), 98 survivors (100352K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 111345.420 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=50782 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 2693168K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 1321 young (1352704K), 98 survivors (100352K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 111345.608 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=50783 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 1469858K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 97 young (99328K), 97 survivors (99328K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 111346.770 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=50783 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 2274082K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 882 young (903168K), 97 survivors (99328K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 111346.959 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=50784 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 1457712K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 62 young (63488K), 62 survivors (63488K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 111348.567 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=50784 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 2727856K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 1299 young (1330176K), 62 survivors (63488K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 111348.696 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=50785 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 3145728K, used 1485552K [0x0000000700000000, 0x0000000700106000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 86 young (88064K), 86 survivors (88064K)
 Metaspace       used 197130K, capacity 202198K, committed 206244K, reserved 1232896K
  class space    used 22121K, capacity 23031K, committed 23756K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 111133.233 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x0000000004313528 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.236 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x0000000004313528 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.236 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000576ddd4 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.236 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000576ddd4 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.236 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x0000000004313528 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.237 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000576ddd4 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.237 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x0000000004313528 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.237 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x000000000576ddd4 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.237 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x0000000004313528 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34
Event: 111133.237 Thread 0x000000004bcc9800 Uncommon trap: reason=range_check action=none pc=0x0000000004313528 method=sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.current()C @ 34

Classes redefined (10 events):
Event: 13655.261 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve, count=9
Event: 13655.750 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve, count=9
Event: 13656.279 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve, count=9
Event: 13656.812 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection, count=9
Event: 13657.667 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl, count=17
Event: 13658.035 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=java.rmi.server.RemoteServer, count=9
Event: 13658.524 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport, count=9
Event: 13659.261 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=java.sql.CallableStatement, count=9
Event: 13659.766 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=java.sql.PreparedStatement, count=9
Event: 13660.446 Thread 0x000000001f9af000 redefined class name=java.sql.DatabaseMetaData, count=9

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 111338.446 Thread 0x0000000049311000 Exception <a 'java/lang/InterruptedException'> (0x00000007bf300ca0) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\objectMonitor.cpp, line 1684]
Event: 111339.637 Thread 0x0000000049311000 Exception <a 'java/lang/InterruptedException'> (0x00000007bce178a8) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\objectMonitor.cpp, line 1684]
Event: 111339.654 Thread 0x0000000049311000 Exception <a 'java/lang/InterruptedException'> (0x00000007bce17ad0) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\objectMonitor.cpp, line 1684]
Event: 111343.128 Thread 0x000000002a1fa800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0000000787f914f8) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 111344.688 Thread 0x000000002d20f000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0000000796c02f18) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 111345.626 Thread 0x0000000049311000 Exception <a 'java/lang/InterruptedException'> (0x00000007bf984b28) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\objectMonitor.cpp, line 1684]
Event: 111348.132 Thread 0x000000002a1fa800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x0000000783004818) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 111348.253 Thread 0x000000003c725800 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x000000077ebf4d90) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 111348.375 Thread 0x0000000049311000 Exception <a 'java/lang/InterruptedException'> (0x00000007bfe83468) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\objectMonitor.cpp, line 1684]
Event: 111349.702 Thread 0x000000002d20f000 Exception <a 'java/net/SocketTimeoutException': Read timed out> (0x000000078fd966a8) thrown at [C:\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u192\11897\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 735]

Events (10 events):
Event: 111346.960 Executing VM operation: G1IncCollectionPause done
Event: 111346.965 Executing VM operation: GetAllStackTraces
Event: 111346.978 Executing VM operation: GetAllStackTraces done
Event: 111347.323 Thread 0x000000003bcc9000 Thread added: 0x000000003bcc9000
Event: 111348.523 Executing VM operation: GetAllStackTraces
Event: 111348.537 Executing VM operation: GetAllStackTraces done
Event: 111348.563 Executing VM operation: G1IncCollectionPause
Event: 111348.696 Executing VM operation: G1IncCollectionPause done
Event: 111349.687 Executing VM operation: GetAllStackTraces
Event: 111349.701 Executing VM operation: GetAllStackTraces done
--------------- S Y S T E M ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 14393 (10.0.14393.2906)

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 79 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 16776692k(1156280k free), swap 20597344k(3148996k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.192-b12) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_192-b12), built on Oct 6 2018 17:12:23 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

Comment: There's really only a couple of options: it's a JVM bug and you should upgrade your JVM, it's an OS bug and you should upgrade your OS, or you have one (or more) faulty memory modules and you should run a ram test (and replace the failing modules).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with HotSpot Java 8 version 20, and I upgrade it to version 102 and now I don't have the problem anymore.

I think you should change your version of Java